# composer global require laravel/installer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.8

I've tried the first commands from the Laravel documentation

[image]

**composer global require laravel/installer**

I got error

[image]

```
Changed current directory to /Users/bheng/.composer                                      
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/installer                                                 
./composer.json has been updated                                                         
Loading composer repositories with package information                                   
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)                                            
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.               

  Problem 1                                                                              
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/installer v2.0.1                                 
    - Conclusion: remove guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.3                                         
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v2.0.0, v2.0.1].                                                                        
    - Conclusion: don't install guzzlehttp/guzzle 4.2.3                                  
    - laravel/installer v2.0.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0 -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.3.2, 6.3.3].                                                                             
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.1, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.2, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.0, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.1.1, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.0, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.1, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.2, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.2.3, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.0, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.1, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.2, 4.2.3].                          
    - Can only install one of: guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.3.3, 4.2.3].                          
    - Installation request for guzzlehttp/guzzle (locked at 4.2.3) -> satisfiable by guzzlehttp/guzzle[4.2.3].
```

Does anyone know why?

I'm trying to spin out a new Laravel project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it

```
⚡️  Sites  composer global remove laravel/installer
Changed current directory to /Users/bheng/.composer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing laravel/installer (v1.4.1)
  - Removing symfony/filesystem (v3.3.10)
  - Removing guzzlehttp/guzzle (4.2.3)
  - Removing guzzlehttp/streams (2.1.0)
  - Removing symfony/console (v2.6.6)
  - Removing symfony/process (v2.6.6)
Generating autoload files
⚡️  Sites  composer global require laravel/installer
Changed current directory to /Users/bheng/.composer
Using version ^2.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.2.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v4.2.4)
    Downloading: 100%         

  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.10.0)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/contracts (v1.0.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing symfony/console (v4.2.4)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing ralouphie/getallheaders (2.0.5)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.5.2)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.3)
    Loading from cache

  - Installing laravel/installer (v2.0.1)
    Downloading: 100%         

symfony/contracts suggests installing psr/cache (When using the Cache contracts)
symfony/contracts suggests installing psr/container (When using the Service contracts)
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/cache-contracts-implementation ()
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/service-contracts-implementation ()
symfony/contracts suggests installing symfony/translation-contracts-implementation ()
symfony/console suggests installing psr/log (For using the console logger)
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/event-dispatcher ()
symfony/console suggests installing symfony/lock ()
guzzlehttp/guzzle suggests installing psr/log (Required for using the Log middleware)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
⚡️  Sites
```

Answer (score 16):

Most likely you need [`--update-with-all-dependencies`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require) switch:

```
composer global require laravel/installer --update-with-all-dependencies
```

Composer refuses to upgrade package if it will require upgrading already installed dependencies - `--update-with-all-dependencies` is for change this behavior and upgrade also all necessary dependencies.